# Problems with all values output to 1 in evaluation metrics

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

```
x_test,x_val,y_test,y_val = train_test_split(x_test,y_test,test_size=0.5) 
print(x_train.shape) 
#(1413, 3)   <----Result

print(x_val.shape)   
#(472, 3)    <----Result

print(x_test.shape)  
#(471, 3)    <----Result
```

I proceeded with data split using machine learning and got the above results.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

dTree = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=2,random_state=0).fit(x_train,y_train)
print("train score : {}".format(dTree.score(x_train, y_train)))
#train score : 1.0   <----Result

print("val score : {}".format(dTree.score(x_val, y_val)))
#val score : 1.0     <----Result
```

We then used Decision Tree to print out the score of train and val, respectively, and the results were all 1.

```
predict_y = dTree.predict(x_test) 

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report 
print(classification_report(y_test, dTree.predict(x_test))) 
print("test score : {}".format(dTree.score(x_test, y_test)))

               precision    recall  f1-score   support

          A       1.00      1.00      1.00       235
          B       1.00      1.00      1.00       236

      accuracy                        1.00       471
     macro avg    1.00      1.00      1.00       471
  weighted avg    1.00      1.00      1.00       471

 test score : 0.9978768577494692
```

Finally, classification_report also showed the above results. Are some of my data splits wrong? Or Does the value of 1 mean all datas perfectly classified?If I'm wrong, I want to hear the right solution.

Comment: Seems like you have a perfect classification model. I would suggest making the train test split as 0.7 or 0.8 though.

Comment: @AkashDubey Is it okay for some blanks to occur in the precision and recall values? Thank you also for your advice on the split ratio.

Comment: Anytime your prediction is _too_ good it's always worth exploring why: Is it that your inputs are able to perfectly recreate your target? In that case you don't really need to do a ML-based classification. Is there _data leakage_ between the predictors and the target? This is a very common problem

Comment: I am not sure If I completely understand. What do you mean by blanks here ?

Comment: @AkashDubey Please see the `Accuracy` part in the result of the classification_report. There are some Missing parts.

Comment: @G.Anderson As you say, there has been a tendency to be categorized clearly in the Feature column, but some are not. So I personally don't think the result can be a perfect one. Is there something wrong? When I checked with sns.heatmap, it generally showed results between 0.94 to 1.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you mean. If you have any variables which are 1:1 correlated with the target variable, then that's data leakage as including that feature variable acts as a proxy for the target

Comment: @G.Anderson Oh, I think you're right. I think I need to clarify the distinction between test data and validation data. Thank you.